# Refresh a webpage just once after 5 seconds

Tags: refresh, html

I'm looking for a JavaScript solution (or whatever else) that will refresh a webpage ONLY once, after 5 seconds it has been opened. Is this possible without being stuck in a refresh loop?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
setTimeout(function ()
    {
        if (self.name != '_refreshed_'){
        self.name = '_refreshed_';
        self.location.reload(true);
    } else {
        self.name = ''; 
    }
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in **many** different ways, but I think the easiest would be to add a query string to the url after the refresh, allowing us to tell if the refresh has already occurred:

```
//Function to get query string value. Source: http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/JavaScript-QueryString-ParseGet-QueryString-with-Client-Side-JavaScript.aspx
function getQuerystring(key, default_){
  if (default_==null) default_=""; 
  key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
  var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(qs == null)
    return default_;
  else
    return qs[1];
}

//check if our query string is already set:
if(getQuerystring(r) !== 1){
  setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = window.location.href + '?r=1'},5000)
}
```

If there is the possibility that a query string is already present, you will have to account for that and change the '?' to an '&'.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass some sort of data between page loads. This can be done in a multitude of ways — use a cookie, a URL query parameter, or something on the server side. Query parameter example:

```
if (!location.search.match(/(\?|&|^)stopRefreshing(=|&|$)/))
{
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        var search = location.search;
        location.search = search ? search + '&stopRefreshing' : 'stopRefreshing';
    }, 5000);
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsbin.com/ofawuz/edit

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you don't mind using jquery you can do it via an ajax call after waiting 5 seconds. Just throwing you some sample code:

[How to wait 5 seconds with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836105/how-to-wait-5-seconds-with-jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        // Get data
        $.ajax({
            url : '/tommyStockExchange/Data',
            dataType : 'html',
            data : {
                'format' : 'H',
                'type' : 'E'
            },
            success : function(data) {
                $("#executions").html(data);
            },
            statusCode : {
                404 : function() {
                    alert('executions url 404 :(');
                }
            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: This neither refreshes the page, nor has anything to do with avoiding a refresh loop. -1

Answer (score 0):

Make it redirect to the same page with a different #hash and in JS only register the redirect if the hash isn't set.