# ScrollTo with animation

Tags: javascript, scrollto

how can i add an easing/animation/slowly moving to this function? 
At the moment it just jumps. 
Now it should move to the "anchor" with an animation.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        setTimeout("window.scrollBy(0,270);",3000);
</script>
```

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: Consider using some existing library for it.

Comment: this one sound good, but how can i add the time after how many seconds the page should scroll  http://flesler.blogspot.se/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it myself. because of wordpress and the jquery.noConflict Mode i hade to modify the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
            $('body').scrollTo( '300px', 2500 );
        }, 3000);
        });
        }(jQuery));
</script>
```

thanks for everybody!!!

Answer (score 46):

also possible with plain javascript using request animation frame..

```
// first add raf shim
// http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

// main function
function scrollToY(scrollTargetY, speed, easing) {
    // scrollTargetY: the target scrollY property of the window
    // speed: time in pixels per second
    // easing: easing equation to use

    var scrollY = window.scrollY,
        scrollTargetY = scrollTargetY || 0,
        speed = speed || 2000,
        easing = easing || 'easeOutSine',
        currentTime = 0;

    // min time .1, max time .8 seconds
    var time = Math.max(.1, Math.min(Math.abs(scrollY - scrollTargetY) / speed, .8));

    // easing equations from https://github.com/danro/easing-js/blob/master/easing.js
    var PI_D2 = Math.PI / 2,
        easingEquations = {
            easeOutSine: function (pos) {
                return Math.sin(pos * (Math.PI / 2));
            },
            easeInOutSine: function (pos) {
                return (-0.5 * (Math.cos(Math.PI * pos) - 1));
            },
            easeInOutQuint: function (pos) {
                if ((pos /= 0.5) < 1) {
                    return 0.5 * Math.pow(pos, 5);
                }
                return 0.5 * (Math.pow((pos - 2), 5) + 2);
            }
        };

    // add animation loop
    function tick() {
        currentTime += 1 / 60;

        var p = currentTime / time;
        var t = easingEquations[easing](p);

        if (p < 1) {
            requestAnimFrame(tick);

            window.scrollTo(0, scrollY + ((scrollTargetY - scrollY) * t));
        } else {
            console.log('scroll done');
            window.scrollTo(0, scrollTargetY);
        }
    }

    // call it once to get started
    tick();
}

// scroll it!
scrollToY(0, 1500, 'easeInOutQuint');
```

Comment: This is a great answer and helped me visualize advanced techniques of using javascript to extend it's own core features. Thanks!

Comment: For IE11 support, you may use `window.pageYOffset` instead of `window.scrollY`.

Comment: Is it possible to use this with elements' .scrollTop property? I can't get it to work for me.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 10 times, this is exactly what I was looking for! This can also be for `scrollBy(dY)` functionality if you calculate targetY as targetY = window.scrollY + offset

Answer (score 23):

For anyone viewing this question in 2019: this can now be done natively by using

```
window.scrollBy({
    top: 0,
    left: 270,
    behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

This works in all major browsers except edge and safari. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy#Examples

Comment: Keep in mind it does not work in IE/Edge: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_scrolltooptions_behavior

Answer (score 13):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24559613/1942069):

```
function scrollBy(distance, duration) {

    var initialY = document.body.scrollTop;
    var y = initialY + distance;
    var baseY = (initialY + y) * 0.5;
    var difference = initialY - baseY;
    var startTime = performance.now();

    function step() {
        var normalizedTime = (performance.now() - startTime) / duration;
        if (normalizedTime > 1) normalizedTime = 1;

        window.scrollTo(0, baseY + difference * Math.cos(normalizedTime * Math.PI));
        if (normalizedTime < 1) window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

This should allow you to smoothly scroll by the specified distance.

Answer (score 4):

**This will Work, Assume you need to Smooth-scrolls to the top of the page.**

```
const scrollToTop = () => {
  const c = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  if (c > 0) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollToTop);
    window.scrollTo(0, c - c / 8);
  }
};
```

Comment: Will this ever finish? Basically, you're doing `c = c * 7/8` and it will never actually touch `0`, right? It will converge to `0` and it will probably eventually be rounded down to `0` by JS due to limited precision, but still.

Answer (score 2):

Another example with jQuery, uses the easing plugin for some nice effects:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

When using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you could easily use the [.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.

[Here's an example on how it should work.](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery makes this much easier, perhaps with the scrollto plugin. http://flesler.blogspot.se/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Consider a solution such:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.1.7.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script><!-- only for other easings than swing or linear -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('html,body').scrollTo( {top:'30%', left:'0px'}, 800, {easing:'easeInBounce'} );
}, 3000);
});
</script>
```

Of course you need to dl the scripts.

See http://jsfiddle.net/7bFAF/2/ for a working example

Comment: and how can i add the time, after how many seconds the page should scroll?

Comment: using jQuery you could easily use timeout just as you suggested yourself for setting the delay, example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836105/how-to-wait-5-seconds-with-jquery

Comment: i tried this..but it does not work.`code` <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('window').delay(3000).scrollTo( 30%,0, 800, {easing:'elasout'} );
  });
  </script> `code`

Comment: @max the "elasout" easing is only defined on the demo page. Other easings but the default swing or linear versions you will need the easing plugin as my example above. also note I edited the function to use timeout() instead of delay() as delay() only works with native jQuery effects. Use timeout() is more general.

Comment: i have no idea what i am doing wrong: this is my code from the head of my wordpress site: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2eyN/

Comment: The function is really nothing wrong with. Hovever the file "http://domain.de/wp-content/themes/intellicig/library/libs/js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3-min.js" Doesn't seem to be there... And for testing purpose try to remove the easing part completely (i suspect you don't want easeInBounce anyway?)...

Comment: he has a problem with the document ready function. http://cl.ly/image/0X02160j2x0g            http://cl.ly/image/0a0m1f3c0a3a

Answer (score 0):

We can make it simpler by using the css property [scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```