# scrollTop animation without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make an animated "scroll to top" effect without using jQuery.

In jQuery, I usually use this code:

```
$('#go-to-top').click(function(){ 
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400);
      return false; 
});
```

How do I animate scrollTop without using jQuery?

Comment: named anchor would do this for you btw, other than javascript.

Comment: anchor doesn't animate the scroll

Comment: And what did you try? And by the way, do you really have multiple go-to-top elements (an ID is unique)?

Comment: Elegant approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/4210821/1671639

Comment: Sounds like a job for CSS3 to me.

Comment: @jfriend00: Since `scrollTop` is not a CSS property, I don’t see how you would animate it with CSS.

Comment: An idea with CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631417/css-pure-css-scroll-animation and an example with plain JS: http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript.

Answer (score 188):

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="scrollToTop(1000);"></button>
```

**1# JavaScript (linear):**

```
function scrollToTop (duration) {
    // cancel if already on top
    if (document.scrollingElement.scrollTop === 0) return;

    const totalScrollDistance = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
    let scrollY = totalScrollDistance, oldTimestamp = null;

    function step (newTimestamp) {
        if (oldTimestamp !== null) {
            // if duration is 0 scrollY will be -Infinity
            scrollY -= totalScrollDistance * (newTimestamp - oldTimestamp) / duration;
            if (scrollY <= 0) return document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 0;
            document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollY;
        }
        oldTimestamp = newTimestamp;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

**2# JavaScript (ease in and out):**

```
function scrollToTop (duration) {
    // cancel if already on top
    if (document.scrollingElement.scrollTop === 0) return;

    const cosParameter = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop / 2;
    let scrollCount = 0, oldTimestamp = null;

    function step (newTimestamp) {
        if (oldTimestamp !== null) {
            // if duration is 0 scrollCount will be Infinity
            scrollCount += Math.PI * (newTimestamp - oldTimestamp) / duration;
            if (scrollCount >= Math.PI) return document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 0;
            document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = cosParameter + cosParameter * Math.cos(scrollCount);
        }
        oldTimestamp = newTimestamp;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
/* 
  Explanation:
  - pi is the length/end point of the cosinus intervall (see below)
  - newTimestamp indicates the current time when callbacks queued by requestAnimationFrame begin to fire.
    (for more information see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)
  - newTimestamp - oldTimestamp equals the delta time

    a * cos (bx + c) + d                        | c translates along the x axis = 0
  = a * cos (bx) + d                            | d translates along the y axis = 1 -> only positive y values
  = a * cos (bx) + 1                            | a stretches along the y axis = cosParameter = window.scrollY / 2
  = cosParameter + cosParameter * (cos bx)  | b stretches along the x axis = scrollCount = Math.PI / (scrollDuration / (newTimestamp - oldTimestamp))
  = cosParameter + cosParameter * (cos scrollCount * x)
*/
```

**Note:**

- Duration in milliseconds (1000ms = 1s)
- Second script uses the cos function. [Example curve](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427elpd4h0r6f0):

[image]

**3# Simple [scrolling library](https://github.com/Robbendebiene/Sliding-Scroll) on Github**

Comment: Keep in mind that `const` is not part of EcmaScript 5, but 6 with different semantics. Currently only Firefox and Chrome support it somehow. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: Yes true, good object. So using var might be the better option untill all browsers are supporting const.

Comment: Can I see a JSFIDDLE of this in action?  I can't seem to get it to work . . .

Comment: Thanks for this! I extended it a bit to allow scrolling to a specific element and a polyfill for browsers without performance.now() ... https://gist.github.com/joshcanhelp/a3a669df80898d4097a1e2c01dea52c1

Comment: This is awesome @Robbendebiene I created a simple scroll-element module based on the linear function above. https://github.com/StevenIseki/scroll-element

Comment: I created a [small library](https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/how-create-jquery-scrollTop-animation-without-jquery/) for that. Provides a few more things like callbacks and the ability to stop the animation as well as using different easing effects. And of course, keeping it small!

Comment: This is not working in IE11. I don't like IE, but still there are 2% o 3% of people using it. How can I fix it?

Comment: Ok, I've found a fix for this: use `pageYOffset` instead of `scrollY`, and it will work even in IE.

Comment: This is brilliant, but has one bug. Sometimes  the cosine's product does not equal exactly 0, resulting in multiple iterations of the scroll's round trip. Solution, along with a mod to support all elements is here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246640/why-is-this-scroll-to-top-function-glitchy)