# Why is this JQuery error happening? Animate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  learning jQuery and trying to work my way around a scroll effect. Anyway, I am trying to make this code work but having trouble in doing so. It breaks when It runs the animate function:

I would really appreciate your help on this one. Thank you.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).animate is not a function
>           at HTMLAnchorElement. (script.js:58)
>           at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)
>           at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)

```js
// Select anchor tags to click on 
$(document).on("click", "a", function(event) {
  console.log("item clicked");

  // Clear out the default action  
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("working until now");

  // Animate to selected selected target
  $("html,body").animate({
    scroll: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
  }, 900);
  console.log("no errors for now");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="javascript/script.js">
</script>
```

Comment: if anyone only want scroll to top use this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24559613/8015878

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's because of the jQuery version you use. `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js`

`slim` version of jQuery does not contain all the original jQuery functions.

You should use a `full` version. You can download it from **[here](https://jquery.com/download/)**.

It will help to better understand if you read this article from
[**here**](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/) where at some point in it you will find this statement and I quote:

> ***Slim build***
>
> Finally, we’ve added something new to this release. Sometimes you
> don’t need ajax, or you prefer to use one of the many standalone
> libraries that focus on ajax requests. And often it is simpler to use
> a combination of CSS and class manipulation for all your web
> animations. Along with the regular version of jQuery that includes the
> ajax and effects modules, we’re releasing a “slim” version that
> excludes these modules. All in all, it excludes ajax, effects, and
> currently deprecated code.

Comment: Indeed, it did not show the error anymore. However my popup effect I used with bootstrap has broken down now. I took a look over the article you've sent me, and it specifies breaking changes would occur. I presume it can affect other implementations with bootstrap  as well. :(  Can you take a look over the code to see if there are any flaws with it ? Merci !

Comment: @DuhanesAndrei, I'm glad it solved the problem. Regarding the problem you have about the popup, please create a https://jsfiddle.net/ with the whole code or create another question and give me the link and I will try to help you.

Comment: Basically I am still trying to make the scroll smooth slide work when clicking on an <a> tag. The fiddle address is https://jsfiddle.net/xczv0kk4/. Thanks so much man!

Comment: @DuhanesAndrei, I don't see any popup there. The fiddle you provided did not included the Bootstrap files or jQuery file. I added them in the fiddle. You mean like when you click the red title should scroll to green one?? Try the update fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/xczv0kk4/1/

Comment: Man, if you were in Cluj I would've bought you a beer! That's what I wanted to make, a scroll effect. And I didn't add the popups just yet, but I am doing it now, and you can take a look.

Comment: @DuhanesAndrei, :). Sunt in Bucuresti, poate cand o sa ajung prin Cluj  :)). I'm glad it helped you and I'm happy to help.

Comment: Stiam ca esti roman : )), mizam ca poate esti de pe aici. I have updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xczv0kk4/2/ . So basically, before changing the jQuery version, the popup worked normally.

Answer (score 7):

slim version will not support some methods hence include this CDN

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

in your project
and then run your code it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
It work for me ----> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

**Example:**

```
<html>
    <title>.....</title>
    <body>
    <!-------------------- scripts --------------------------------->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> <!- use this->

        <script src="js/navbar-fixed.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please descibe what happend??

Comment: how you have found the solution?