# Is Jquery animate() method depreciated without alternate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).animate is not a function

I tried using different versions Jquery.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

but getting the same issue. when i try online code compilers like w3 schools, the examples work, so there is no issue with the browser. I use google chrome by the way. All other Jquery functionalities work except animate. i tried giving time for animation and removing it as well. very frustrating to deal with this.

example:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 2100}, 2500);
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 2100});
```

Comment: Please see a below link It may resolve your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43067581/12434428

Comment: Try to search if the  JQuery is not calling twice. More on Jquery is called before you write your JQuery Code