# Long magnetic scroll page in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript, ionic2

Hey Guys i need your help please,

is started to working on an Ionic 2 App. My Navigation is not that complicated. I have one menu if i click one item another menu opens with a submenu and if i click on an item in the submenu a third page should render above it and this works really fine. Now the third activity should be a very long scrolling site with a lot of section (the sections are on top of each other). And every section should have a toolbar with one back button to go back to the submenu and two arrow keys for the previous or next section.

Here a small picture

[image]

now my problems:

how can i achieve the magnetic part? I think it like so: the Bar sits on the top of the page and above the content. When i scroll the content goes underneath and i can scroll to the end. When iam at the end everything should stop and when i pull further the next Section Bar jumps to the top of my site.

I hope you can help me thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

## [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DCnukHPNWa6Z1zOX53xp?p=preview)

To make this work you need to:

- Create a function that scrolls your `scroll-content` element to the top
- Track the scroll position of `scroll-content`
- Use `*ngIf` on your scroll to top button to conditionally show after `scroll-content` has reached a certain threshold.

## Scroll to top function

I adapted [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24559613/5357459) to apply to the `scroll-content` element

```
scrollToTop(scrollDuration) {
let scrollStep = -this.ionScroll.scrollTop / (scrollDuration / 15);
let scrollInterval = setInterval( () => {
    if ( this.ionScroll.scrollTop != 0 ) {
        this.ionScroll.scrollTop = this.ionScroll.scrollTop + scrollStep;
    } else {
      clearInterval(scrollInterval);
    }
}, 15);
```

## Track `scroll-content` position

This example uses the window height as the threshold for showing the scroll to top button like this:

```
this.ionScroll.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (this.ionScroll.scrollTop > window.innerHeight) {
    this.showButton = true;
  } else {
    this.showButton = false;
  }
});
```

## Button Html

```
<button *ngIf="showButton" (click)="scrollToTop(1000)">Scroll Top</button>
```

## Full component Typescript

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  public ionScroll;
  public showButton = false;
  public contentData = [];

  constructor(public myElement: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Ionic scroll element
    this.ionScroll = this.myElement.nativeElement.children[1].firstChild;
    // On scroll function
    this.ionScroll.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      if (this.ionScroll.scrollTop > window.innerHeight) {
        this.showButton = true;
      } else {
        this.showButton = false;
      }
    });
    // Content data
    for (let i = 0; i < 301; i++) {
      this.contentData.push(i);
    }
  }
  // Scroll to top function
  // Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24559613/5357459
  scrollToTop(scrollDuration) {
    let scrollStep = -this.ionScroll.scrollTop / (scrollDuration / 15);
    let scrollInterval = setInterval( () => {
        if ( this.ionScroll.scrollTop != 0 ) {
            this.ionScroll.scrollTop = this.ionScroll.scrollTop + scrollStep;
        } else {
          clearInterval(scrollInterval);
        }
    }, 15);
  }

}
```

## Full component Html

```
<ion-navbar primary *navbar>
  <ion-title>
    Ionic 2
  </ion-title>
  <button *ngIf="showButton" (click)="scrollToTop(1000)">Scroll Top</button>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content class="has-header" #testElement>
  <div padding style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Ionic 2 Test</h1>
    <div *ngFor="let item of contentData">
      test content-{{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it when I come back from work ;)

Comment: Ồ không có vấn đề, tôi sẽ hạnh phúc nếu bạn bỏ phiếu :p