# Controlling scroll rate in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium

Is there a way to control the rate you scroll down in Java?

```
public static void scrollPage(WebDriver driver) {
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
}
```

This is what I have currently but this scrolls to the bottom automatically.

Comment: possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/q/12199363/5127499

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the scrollHeight by 100 and use a loop to scroll step by step with small delays between the steps.