# Jquery delay not working correctly

Tags: jquery

I want to create a delay between these two messages:

```
$('#submit-account').html(animation + 'Submitting Data')
$('#submit-account').html(animation + 'Validating Email')
```

I have tried this:

```
var ani = "<i class='icon-spin'></i> "
$('#submit-account').html(ani + 'Wait').delay(5000).fadeIn();
$('#submit-account').html(ani + 'Done').delay(10000).fadeIn();
```

But there is no delay, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that problem is  because `delay()` only delays item(s) in a queue (jQuery queues automatically only animations).
So try to modify fade function to `fadeIn(0)` and jQuery will interpret it as animation and now delay should works.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the #submit-account is hidden already.

instead of your code you can try this

```
$('#submit-account').html(ani + "Wait").fadeIn(5000);


 $('#submit-account').html(ani + "Done").fadeIn(5000);
```

This will control the speed of the fadein effect. 
or if you want the div to be fadein after some time, you can use the `setTimeOut()` function.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to link JQuery 1.9.1, this is working: <kbd>[**jsFiddle is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/zXHL8/)</kbd>

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

and note that `delay()` method is for delaying between queued jQuery **effects**.

take a look at this <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/zXHL8/1/)</kbd>

[<sub>**reference**</sub>](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

---

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i'm understanding it precisely or correct but there's a Default Built in JavaScript setTimeOut(); Function.

For more info :[How to wait 5 seconds with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836105/how-to-wait-5-seconds-with-jquery)