# How can I make my JavaScript wait 0.5 seconds before running the next statement?

Tags: javascript

I want to do this

```
statement1;
// rest for 0.5 seconds
statement2;
```

How can I make my JavaScript wait 0.5 seconds?

I tried

```
statement1;
window.setTimer(500);
statement2;
```

But that was not it.  Thanks

Comment: Use setTimeout, look it up.

Comment: Well, `window.setTimer` doesn't exist, so it's not that surprising that it didn't work. Before you try anything, read the documentation of the function you are trying to call. If you can't find documentation than the function might not exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
statement1();
setTimeout(function() {
    statement2();
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put a timer like this
statement1();

```
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
        statement2();
  }, 500);
```

[How to wait 5 seconds with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836105/how-to-wait-5-seconds-with-jquery)