# How do I slow down the execution of a jquery click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, console, delay

I use a simple jquery command in the Google Chrome console to manage my site. Basically, I have to approve a number of new requests every day, so I use:

```
$('.approve').click();
```

where 'approve' is the class name of the button that needs to get clicked. This saves me hours. However, this crashes my browser every time, and sometimes doesn't work, mainly because of the resource taxing it put on my laptop. I was looking for a way to slow down the actions of the function. I tried...

```
$('.approve').click().delay(1000);
```

to try and slow it down by 1 second between button clicks. This didn't seem to work (it ran without errors but I don't think it slowed down the clicking.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Someone pointed out that this may be a duplicate of another question. The reason it isn't is that the other top answer focuses on using JS to define a function that uses setTimeout(), where I am looking for a native jquery method of doing it. I understand jquery is written in JS, but because I'm using it in a command console, I don't have the luxury of multiple lines of coding space.

Can anyone also tell me why the above function wouldn't work? It seems like it should, based on my research.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A *much* better approach would be to figure out why a basic click handler is putting so much strain on your laptop...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait 5 seconds with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836105/how-to-wait-5-seconds-with-jquery)

Comment: Use setTimeout() function.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It might be that the approve button makes a request to the server. Lets imagine OP have thousand of buttons, this will yield the same number of requests.

Comment: Wish we could see more of your code! Another possibility could be that each successive click fires the more times that the previous time due to a common mistakes some developers make when registering an event handler. And if that's coupled with a request to the server then you're in for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait 1 second between each click:

You will need to iterate over each `.approve`-button, then trigger the click event for each button with a second in between: ([`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout))

```
$('.approve').each(function(index) {
    var $approve = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Simulation click event
        $approve.trigger('click'); 
    // 0, 1, 2, 3, ... times 1000 to bring delay to miliseconds
    }, index * 1000); 
});
```

---

One liner (For IE9+):

```
$(".approve").each(function(c){setTimeout(function(c){c.click()},1e3*c,$(this))});
```

One liner:

```
$(".approve").each(function(e){var i=$(this);setTimeout(function(){i.click()},1e3*e)});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a delay on the function click like so

```
$(".approve").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Do something
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exectue your function once, use `setTimeout()`

```
$(".approve").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    }, 1000);
});
```

If you want to exectue it every second, use `setInterval()`

Answer (score 0):

when click you have to run a function that will execute setTimeout function

```
$('.approve').click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
  // here some code u want to execute after 5 sec //
  }, 5000);
});
```