# Fading between images in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some javascript set up so that when I `hover` an image, it changes to a different image. The only problem is, that it's instant. How would I add a transition to this to make it smooth, to fade between the images?

```
<div class="social">
    <ul class="sociallinks">
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/lee-jordan">
                <img class="linkedinIcon" src="assets/images/linkedin.png" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://github.com/loxol">
                <img class="githubIcon" src="assets/images/github.png" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".linkedinIcon").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "assets/images/linkedinhover.png");
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "assets/images/linkedin.png");
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait 5 seconds with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836105/how-to-wait-5-seconds-with-jquery)

Comment: @Tyler How is that a duplicate?

Comment: he wants to add a delay to his image fading, the linked question is about creating delays with jquery. Also, a comment on that question talks about the accepted answer being perfect for delays ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836105/how-to-wait-5-seconds-with-jquery#comment13858205_1836140 ). Putting that aside, a simple google on jquery delays gave up many results... It's unlikely this user has done much research on his specific question.

Comment: I think you should read the question again. Or at least the title! Timouts and delays will not help. He don't want a delay to fading, he want fading at all! Just tagging a question as duplicate when not understanding the question is not a good idea. @Tyler

Comment: @eisbeher He says "How would I add a transition delay to this to make it smooth?" That's talking about delays there...

Comment: Beside that you still not understand this sentence, where is the `transition` in your duplicate? @Tyler

Comment: @eisbehr well for example, in the accept answer it mentions .delay() function and link to the page for that method: http://api.jquery.com/delay/  This page also displays an runnable example with fading, both a wait time and a transitional fade. The OP (of the linked question) also mentions "the success message on the screen fades out" (fades out will often use a transitional delay)

Comment: I give up, it's no use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it on different ways, but you can't fade the same image when replacing the `src`. You could use two `img` tags, or even place the `hover` image as background of the `img` tag, and fade out the image on hover using css `transitions`. Here is one example:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".linkedinIcon").hover(function() {
        $(this).css("opacity", 0);
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("opacity", 1);
    });
});
```

```css
ul.sociallinks {
  list-style: none;
}
ul.sociallinks a {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
ul.sociallinks img {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="social">
  <ul class="sociallinks">
    <li>
      <a href="#" style="background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/300x200/2e97c7/2e97c7&text=2');">
        <img class="linkedinIcon" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/c72cc7/c72cc7&text=1" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Even possible without JS at all, css only:

```css
ul.sociallinks {
  list-style: none;
}
ul.sociallinks a {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
ul.sociallinks img {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
ul.sociallinks img:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <ul class="sociallinks">
    <li>
      <a href="#" style="background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/300x200/2e97c7/2e97c7&text=2');">
        <img class="linkedinIcon" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/c72cc7/c72cc7&text=1" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain css3 solution:

```css
ul.sociallinks a img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 250px;
}
.animate {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
.changeDisplayOnHover .showOnHover {
  opacity: 0;
}
.changeDisplayOnHover .hideOnHover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.changeDisplayOnHover:hover .showOnHover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.changeDisplayOnHover:hover .hideOnHover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <ul class="sociallinks">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="changeDisplayOnHover">
        <img class="hideOnHover animate" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_8107bb8004a8_128.png" />
        <img class="showOnHover animate" src="http://www.aqua-soft.org/forum/uploads/post-25-1229846653.png" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

2 effects using CSS:

```css
.changeableImage {
 background:url(http://cdn.quotesgram.com/small/94/89/854123786-colorful-nature-wallpaper.jpg);
 display:block;
 width:300px;
 height:200px;
 transition: padding 2s;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 overflow: hidden;
}


.changeableImage:hover{
 padding-top:200px;
}


.changeableBG {
 background:url(http://cdn.quotesgram.com/small/94/89/854123786-colorful-nature-wallpaper.jpg);
 display:block;
 width:300px;
 height:200px;
 transition: padding 2s;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.changeableBG img{
 display:block;
 width:300px;
 height:200px;
 transition: all 2s;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}


.changeableBG img:hover{
 transform: translateY(200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <ul class="sociallinks">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img class="changeableImage" src="http://free4kwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/nature/Colorful-UHD-4K-Mountains-Wallpaper-300x200.jpg" />
      </a>
      <br>
      <a class="changeableBG" href="#">
        <img  src="http://free4kwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/nature/Colorful-UHD-4K-Mountains-Wallpaper-300x200.jpg" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```