# I want to set current time line(if possible auto move after every 10 minutes) in html table with red color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am using this html table , i want to set current time line in html td. For example current time is 9 AM then set current time line on 9 AM column if time is 10 AM then current time line move to next column.Please help me  if any plugin related to this task tell me.Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="table-responsive custom">
    <div class="col-sm-1 mov_div"></div>
        <table class="table table-bordered ">
            <thead>        
                 <tr>                                      
                    <th></th>
                    <th><p>Queed</p></th>
                    <th><p>7:00</p></th>
                    <th><p>8:00</p></th>
                    <th><p>9:00</p></th>
                    <th><p>10:00</p></th>
                    <th><p>11:00</p></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="context-menu-one">
                <!--  <tr> </tr> -->
                 <tr>
                    <td>data1</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><img id="vesselIcon1" src="vesselsIcon/vess-arriving.gif" style= "width:90px;"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Some Content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>data2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><img id="vesselIcon2" src="vesselsIcon/vess-arriving.gif" style= "width:90px;"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td>data 3</td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td><img id="vesselIcon3" src="vesselsIcon/vess-arriving.gif" style= "width:90px;"/></td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
  </div>
```

**My html table like this image**

[image]

**I Want like time line like below image**

[image]

Comment: Where is the code you've tried to get this line showing?  Please publish your javascript.

Comment: I am just try to add line through css . You have any idea how to to in java script.

Comment: You will need to work with the Date object or if you want a library, look into moment.js.  Add the line and move it accordingly at an appropriate interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem using jQuery `setTimeout` function. Added line and In every one-minute moving the line using `setTimeout` function.

```
setTimeout( function() {
    // code
  }, 1000 );
```

Useful links for setTimeout.

1. [How to wait 5 seconds with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836105/how-to-wait-5-seconds-with-jquery/1836140#1836140)
2. https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Answer (score 1):

You can use line class div.
Please try this code.

```css
 .line{
    z-index:20;
    position:absolute;
    left:100;
    width: 2px;
    height: 200px;
    border-right: 2px solid green;
    position: absolute;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: your css ok for line , but i want to that line move with table when i scroll .

Comment: you can edit style in javascript, when scroll you can change the left style of that class

Comment: Yes its work for me , when i change style in javascript