# Delay a jquery plugin by seconds, scroll y or exit intent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, delay

Every time I ask a question here, no matter how dumb it is, I do always learn something.
Anyway, I'm hoping to get some more good answers to this one.
I'm calling a jquery plugin for a modal on document.ready

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Initialize the plugin
      $('#JPO').popup({
        absolute: false,
        autoopen: true
        
      });
      $.fn.popup.defaults.pagecontainer = '#page'
    });
  </script>
```

it auto opens a modal but I only want the modal to open after either a user scrolls down 400px, or after being on the page for 5 seconds, or on exit (exit intent).

This is the jquery plugin I'm using: https://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wait 5 seconds with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836105/how-to-wait-5-seconds-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

use `setTimeout()` function.

[Read More about setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

**Sample Code:**

```
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    //do something special
  }, 5000);
```

Comment: that will work well for a timer. I need to find a way to read an exit intent by the user.

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve? plz elaborate more.

Comment: I want my pop up to appear when the user goes to close the tab, I also want it to appear after 5 seconds of being on the page.

Comment: which tab? please post HTML code to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of setTimeout, and onmouseleave to create my popup.

```
 <script>      
      function openPopup(){
        $('#JPO').popup({
      autoopen: true,
          detatch: true,
          transition: 'all 1.0s'
    });      
      };
      
      function exitPopup(){
            $('#JPO').popup('show');
            };
       
       function cookiePopup(){
         $('#JPO').popup({
           autoopen: false,
           detatch: true,
           transition: 'all 1.0s'
         });
       };
     
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.modal-content').hide();
  
  var dialogShown = Cookies.get('dialogShown');
  if (!dialogShown) {
        
        setTimeout(openPopup, {{ section.settings.delay }});
        $(document).mouseleave(function(){
          setTimeout(exitPopup,1050)
        });
    Cookies.set('dialogShown', 1, { expires: 1 });
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(cookiePopup, {{ section.settings.delay }});
  }
});
</script>
```

I also used a plugin called js-cookie to make my pop-up less annoying to repeat visitors.
PS. this is for a shopify section, so it does contain some liquid.

Plugins used:

- PopUp https://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/
- Cookies https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v1.5.1